# Datepicker ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to apply locale on old datepicker

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

I have tried evrything and i dont know where to look further, i can use the new one, but i have big solution that i have to stay on old datepicker

Here is what i have

**my.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        DatepickerModule.forRoot() 
    ],
    declarations: [

    ],
    providers: [

    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/bs-moment';
import { de } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
defineLocale('de', de);


@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {}
```

**my.component.html**

```
  <datepicker formControlName="effectiveDate" [showWeeks]="false" [locale]="de">
```

Can't bind to 'locale' since it isn't a known property of 'datepicker'. :(

Comment: For the legacy version of this datepicker, I do not see `locale` listed as an available input.

Comment: Yes, but how to add locale for legacy version, that is my question?

Comment: You can't just simply add inputs to a third-party library without forking it and modifying the source.  Why not use the updated version?  It contains a `locale`.

Comment: I can not update

Comment: It looks like both the legacy version and new version are in the exact same library, just change which module you import.  One is `DatepickerModule`, the new one is `BsDatepickerModule`.

Comment: If i import new i got this error 
Error: Template parse errors:
'datepicker' is not a known element:
1. If 'datepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("                                        </div>

                                                    [ERROR ->]<datepicker formControlName="effectiveDate">

Comment: @MiomirDancevic that last suggests you don't DatepickerModule imported into your module. Can you check that?

Comment: It is not working legacy datepicker does not support locale

Answer (score 0):

The legacy version of this datepicker does not contain a `locale` input.  Documentation states `This is a legacy version of datepicker without support of daterangepicker, locales, themes, etc.`  The newer version does have a locale, but it cannot be modified as an input property.  Instead you use the `BsLocaleService` to change the locale.  It should look something like this:

**my.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BsDatepickerModule, BsLocaleService  } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { de } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
defineLocale('de', de);

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BsDatepickerModule.forRoot() 
    ],
    declarations: [

    ],
    providers: [
        BsLocaleService 
    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```
import { BsDatepickerConfig, BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { listLocales } from 'ngx-bootstrap/bs-moment';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   locale = 'de';

   constructor(private _localeService: BsLocaleService) {}

   ngOnInit(){
      this._localeService.use(this.locale);
   }

}
```

**my.component.html**

```
<input placeholder="Datepicker" type="text" formControlName="effectiveDate" class="form-control" bsDatepicker #dp="bsDatepicker">
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for BsLocaleService!

Comment: Sorry, left that off the `providers`.  Updated.

Comment: I have changed to BsDatePicker as you write, but now i got this error

Error: Template parse errors:
'datepicker' is not a known element:
1. If 'datepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("                                        </div>

                                                    [ERROR ->]<datepicker formControlName="effectiveDate">

Comment: My bad.  I was trying to update your code, and left off that the new version is a directive not a component, so use the `bsDatepicker` directive.

Comment: This in not answer to my question, we have updated the datepicker, i dont need that i need to update locale on old datepicker

Comment: The legacy datepicker documentation is pretty clear that it does not support locale.